# Wrong Key Usage in Encryption of SOAP Request

Tags: java, spring, encryption, certificate, soap-client

I am trying to send SOAP request with using some keystore.jks. And it uses encryption during creating a request. But I see an error during this process in my application server logs. Error is below;

```
[8/9/22 9:13:43:280 EET] 00000061 Wss4jSecurity E org.springframework.ws.soap.security.AbstractWsSecurityInterceptor handleSecurementException Could not secure response: Error during encryption: ; nested exception is: 
    org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: Cannot encrypt data; nested exception is: 
    java.security.InvalidKeyException: Wrong key usage; nested exception is org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: Error during encryption: ; nested exception is: 
    org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: Cannot encrypt data; nested exception is: 
    java.security.InvalidKeyException: Wrong key usage
                                 org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecuritySecurementException: Error during encryption: ; nested exception is: 
    org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: Cannot encrypt data; nested exception is: 
    java.security.InvalidKeyException: Wrong key usage; nested exception is org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: Error during encryption: ; nested exception is: 
    org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: Cannot encrypt data; nested exception is: 
    java.security.InvalidKeyException: Wrong key usage
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor.secureMessage(Wss4jSecurityInterceptor.java:523)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.security.AbstractWsSecurityInterceptor.handleRequest(AbstractWsSecurityInterceptor.java:203)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:578)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:537)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:384)
    at com......IbsWebServiceClient.marshalSendAndReceive(IbsWebServiceClient.java:42)
    at com......getBakiyeler(NktServisImpl.java:76)
    at com......IbsWebServiceImpl.getBakiyeler(IbsWebServiceImpl.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver$1.invoke(InstanceResolver.java:246)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:146)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler.invoke(EndpointMethodHandler.java:257)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:598)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:557)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:542)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:439)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:243)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:471)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:244)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:135)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:129)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:160)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSSpringServlet.doPost(WSSpringServlet.java:52)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1232)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:781)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:480)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at com.......RequestResponseLogFilter.doFilter(RequestResponseLogFilter.java:81)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.......RequestContextFilter.doFilter(RequestContextFilter.java:41)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:947)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
Caused by: org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: Error during encryption: ; nested exception is: 
    org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: Cannot encrypt data; nested exception is: 
    java.security.InvalidKeyException: Wrong key usage
    at org.apache.ws.security.action.EncryptionAction.execute(EncryptionAction.java:79)
    at org.apache.ws.security.handler.WSHandler.doSenderAction(WSHandler.java:202)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jHandler.doSenderAction(Wss4jHandler.java:120)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor.secureMessage(Wss4jSecurityInterceptor.java:520)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: Cannot encrypt data; nested exception is: 
    java.security.InvalidKeyException: Wrong key usage
    at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecEncryptedKey.prepareInternal(WSSecEncryptedKey.java:216)
    at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecEncrypt.prepare(WSSecEncrypt.java:221)
    at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecEncrypt.build(WSSecEncrypt.java:262)
    at org.apache.ws.security.action.EncryptionAction.execute(EncryptionAction.java:77)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Wrong key usage
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecEncryptedKey.prepareInternal(WSSecEncryptedKey.java:214)
    ... 64 more
```

Request encryption on my spring context looks like below;

```
<bean id="ibsWSSecurityInterceptorEnc" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor" >
        <property name="securementActions" value="Encrypt"/>
        <property name="securementEncryptionUser" value="${encrypt.username}"/>
        <property name="securementEncryptionSymAlgorithm" value="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"/>
       <property name="securementEncryptionKeyTransportAlgorithm" value="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5"/>
        <property name="securementEncryptionParts" value="{Content}{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body"/>
        <property name="securementEncryptionCrypto">
            <ref bean="keystore"/> 
        </property>     
    </bean>
```

And my chain certificates like below;

```
---- BEGIN X.509 CERTIFICATE #1/3----
Owner=
  EMAILADDRESS=..., CN=123, OU=..., O=..., L=..., ST=..., C=...
Issuer=
  CN=Test CA, O=..., C=..
Version=3
Serial Number=...
Valid From=Friday, August 5, 2022 3:31 PM
Valid Until=Thursday, August 5, 2027 3:32 PM
Signature Algorithm=SHA256withRSA
Fingerprints=
    MD5:     ...
    SHA1:    ...
Key Usage= critical
    List:
    . digitalSignature
    . keyEncipherment
    . keyAgreement
Extended Key Usage= none
---- END X.509 CERTIFICATE #1/3 ----

---- BEGIN X.509 CERTIFICATE #2/3----
Owner=
  CN=Test CA, O=..., C=...
Issuer=
  CN=Root CA, O=..., C=...
Version=3
Serial Number=...
Valid From=Friday, July 29, 2022 9:47 AM
Valid Until=Thursday, July 30, 2037 9:48 AM
Signature Algorithm=SHA256withRSA
Fingerprints=
    MD5:     ...
    SHA1:    ...
Key Usage= critical
    List:
    . keyCertSign
    . cRLSign
Extended Key Usage= none
---- END X.509 CERTIFICATE #2/3 ----

---- BEGIN X.509 CERTIFICATE #3/3----
Owner=
  CN=Root CA, O=..., C=...
Issuer=
  CN=Root CA, O=..., C=...
Version=3
Serial Number=...
Valid From=Thursday, July 7, 2022 11:23 AM
Valid Until=Saturday, July 12, 2042 11:23 AM
Signature Algorithm=SHA256withRSA
Fingerprints=
    MD5:     ...
    SHA1:    ...
Key Usage= critical
    List:
    . keyCertSign
    . cRLSign
Extended Key Usage= none
---- END X.509 CERTIFICATE #3/3 ----
```

Code works before I changed my certificates. And older chain certificate looks like below;

```
---- BEGIN X.509 CERTIFICATE #1/3----
Owner=
  C=..., O=..., CN=123
Issuer=
  C=..., O=..., CN=Test CA
Version=3
Serial Number=787F4CACCEFCF994
Valid From=Wednesday, April 29, 2020 5:13 PM
Valid Until=Tuesday, April 29, 2025 5:13 PM
Signature Algorithm=SHA256withRSA
Fingerprints=
    MD5:     ...
    SHA1:    ...
Key Usage= critical
    List:
    . digitalSignature
    . nonRepudation
    . keyEncipherment
    . dataEncipherment
Extended Key Usage= not critical
    List:
    . serverAuth
    . clientAuth
---- END X.509 CERTIFICATE #1/3 ----

---- BEGIN X.509 CERTIFICATE #2/3----
Owner=
  C=..., O=..., CN=Test CA
Issuer=
  C=..., O=..., CN=Root CA
Version=3
Serial Number=...
Valid From=Wednesday, December 4, 2013 11:10 AM
Valid Until=Sunday, December 3, 2028 12:10 PM
Signature Algorithm=SHA256withRSA
Fingerprints=
    MD5:     ...
    SHA1:    ...
Key Usage= critical
    List:
    . digitalSignature
    . keyCertSign
    . cRLSign
Extended Key Usage= none
---- END X.509 CERTIFICATE #2/3 ----

---- BEGIN X.509 CERTIFICATE #3/3----
Owner=
  C=..., O=..., CN=Root CA
Issuer=
  C=..., O=..., CN=Root CA
Version=3
Serial Number=...
Valid From=Monday, February 25, 2013 2:47 PM
Valid Until=Friday, February 25, 2033 3:47 PM
Signature Algorithm=SHA256withRSA
Fingerprints=
    MD5:     ...
    SHA1:    ...
Key Usage= critical
    List:
    . digitalSignature
    . keyCertSign
    . cRLSign
Extended Key Usage= none
---- END X.509 CERTIFICATE #3/3 ----
```

It seems that the key usage list in the certificate has changed. But I couldn't find how to find a solution.

Edit: It is a really old software that we use. Dependencies like below;

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
            <classifier>all</classifier>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: What library (version and from where) are you using? The only online source I find for that class is in https://github.com/wso2/wso2-wss4j/tree/master/modules/wss4j but it has the relevant Cipher.init call on line 207 not 214 and more importantly uses the PublicKey overload which does not have this check and exception rather than the Certificate overload which does -- and according to git hasn't changed since 2014.

Comment: I add dependencies. Versions are old. Thank you.

Comment: I solved the problem by updating wss4j version to 1.6.8. Thanks for pointing this out.